# C language - removing uninitialized space in string

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
char *string = malloc(strlen(stringa) + strlen(stringb) + 1);
strcpy(string, stringa);
strcpy(string+strlen(stringa), stringb);
```

the problem is, with what I'm doing, `stringa` is sometimes NULL, and when it is and it gets copied to `string`, it results in uninitialized characters at the very beginning of `string`. Here's an example of the output that I am getting when stringa happens to be NULL:

```
�����o
This is a test
To see the output
of string
```

I want to get rid of the characters at the beginning that are uninitialized. What I tried doing so far is:

```
memset(string, 0, strlen(string));
```

and

```
memset(string, 0, sizeof(string));
```

both have given me errors and do not solve my problem. Anyone know how I could edit 'string' to get rid of the uninitialized characters? This could either be applied to 'string' directly or to 'stringa' before it gets copied to 'string'.

Comment: How about test `stringa` for NULL and handle accordingly (ie, only copy if not NULL)?

Comment: `strcpy`ing from NULL is going to straight up crash on some systems. (i'm amazed it isn't on yours.) so you should just avoid doing that in the first place. like: `if(stringa!=NULL) strcpy(string, stringa);`

Comment: `strlen(NULL)` is undefined behaviour. You must alter your logic to avoid calling this.

Comment: Prior to `malloc()`, `if (stringa == NULL) stringa = "";`  OTOH, what do you want if _both_ are `NULL`?

Answer (score 1):

You can always run some logical tests with a conditional statement on the value of the strings before you begin copying them:

**Option 1:**

```
char*  string;
size_t length = 0;

if (stringa != NULL) {
    length += strlen(stringa);
}

if (stringb != NULL) {
    length += strlen(stringb);
}

string = malloc(length + 1);

// Copy the strings
```

**Option 2:**

```
char* string = NULL;

if (stringa != NULL) {
    string = malloc(strlen(stringa) + 1);
    strcpy(string, stringa);
}

if (stringb != NULL) {
    if (string != NULL) {
        string = realloc(string, strlen(stringb) + 1);
        strcat(string, stringb);
    } else {
        string = malloc(strlen(stringb) + 1);
        strcpy(string, stringb);
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't crash (yet) but `string` remains uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

In very old C, on many platforms, a nul byte happened to be hardcoded to location zero in memory, and so there wasn't a distinction between the null string and the empty string. It's a bit of an odd difference if you think of it, no string of sausages versus a string of no sausages.

You can easily resurrect the old behaviour, by wrapping strcpy

```
char *strcpy_oldbehaviour(char *dest, const char *src)
{
   if(src)
     return strcpy(dest, src);
   else
     return strcpy(dest, "");
}
```